# Using cPanel API to create mySQL database and user in PHP

Tags: php, api, cpanel, whm

I am trying to create a mysql user and assign it to the created database.

I have tried setting $db_host as IP address, FQD, localhost (since I am running from the same server) etc. All of these has no success.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? (xmlapi.php is being incuded fine)

```
include("xmlapi.php");
$db_host = "usingfullyqualifieddomain";
$cpuser = "myuser";
$cppass = "mypass";

$xmlapi = new xmlapi($db_host);
$xmlapi->set_port(2083);
$xmlapi->password_auth($cpuser,$cppass);
$xmlapi->set_debug(1);
//create database
print $xmlapi->api1_query($cpuser, "Mysql", "adddb", 'myDatabaseName');
//create user
print $xmlapi->api1_query($cpuser, "Mysql", "adduser", array('user' => 'myDBUser','pass'=>'myDBPwd'));
```

Comment: Did you get solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably related to the way you're making your first service call, to create the database. Here is how I do it, on CPanel 11:

```
$auth_user = 'XXXXXX'; 
$auth_pass = 'XXXXX'; 
$server = 'XXXXXXXX.com';
$json_client = new \xmlapi($server);

$json_client->set_output('json'); 
$json_client->set_port(2083); 
$json_client->password_auth($auth_user, $auth_pass);
$json_client->set_debug(1);

# Create Database
$result = $json_client->api1_query( $auth_user, 'Mysql', 'adddb', array($shop->alias));
var_dump($result);
```

Note that the fourth parameter should be an array with the parameters, and not a string as you are doing it.

Also notice that the print on the api call result is not very useful for debugging. Try var_dump'ing it, as it will show you some more interesting information to work on.

Comment: api 1 is obsolete. please use api2

Answer (score 1):

currently, cpanel support the cpanel json api..
here you can use this code ..
this worked for me well

```
<?php 

$cpanelusername = "cpanelusername";
$cpanelpassword = "cpanelpassword";  
$domain = 'mydomain.com';
   
$query = "https://$domain:2083/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_module=Mysql&cpanel_jsonapi_func=adddb&cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=1&arg-0=DBNAME";

$curl = curl_init();                                // Create Curl Object
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);       // Allow self-signed certs
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);       // Allow certs that do not match the hostname
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);               // Do not include header in output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);       // Return contents of transfer on curl_exec
$header[0] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($cpanelusername.":".$cpanelpassword) . "\n\r";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);    // set the username and password
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);            // execute the query
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result == false) {
    error_log("curl_exec threw error \"" . curl_error($curl) . "\" for $query");   
                                                    // log error if curl exec fails
}
curl_close($curl);

print $result;

?>
```